# order a data.table based on a character column with a specific (not alphabetical) order in mind

Tags: r, data.table

I want to order a data table based on a character vector specified manually.

```
library(data.table)
DT = data.table(x=c("c","b","a"), y=1:3)
```

I can order it alphabetically with:

```
DT[order(x)]
```

but can I order it based on a character vector like:

```
preferred.order <- c("b","a","c")
```

with the goal being:

```
data.table(x=c("b","a","c"), y=c(2,1,3))
```

In reality, I have a data.table with collected outputs and the variable names in the first column. For presentation purposes, I want those variables in a specific (not alphabetical) order.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One possibility is to join on the preferred order:

```
DT[preferred.order, on="x"]
   x y
1: b 2
2: a 3
3: c 1
```

Note that this requires the preferred.order vector contains all elements in `DT$x` and has no duplicates.

As an alternative, you could create a factor variable of `DT$x` with the preferred ordering and then use `setorder` to order DT by reference.

```
DT[, xFac := factor(x, levels=preferred.order)]
setorder(DT, xFac)
```

which returns

```
DT
   x y xFac
1: b 2    b
2: a 3    a
3: c 1    c
```

Which method is preferable will vary on the use-case.

Comment: the factor variable works. Good idea! I think that one would work with duplicates as well (of which I have none).